# How to fuzz restricted shell?

Tags: fuzzing

I want to fuzz the restricted shell which is customized linux shell. I can only run certain commands which are specific to application. OS commands are not allowed to run. The shell looks as below after doing ssh to it,

[image]

My goal is to fuzz the input parameters for this shell and observe the crashes and unexpected errors. I am looking for the tools and process to fuzz these kinds of restricted shells.

Does anyone recommend a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/23499/24222

Comment: There is no way to install the tools to run fuzzing. Need to ssh first and then pass commands (limited commands)

Comment: Ok, you could use an SSH library to programmatically fuzz over the SSH connection.